# SSIS - Filter duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have a table (Id, ArticleCode, StoreCode, Adress, Number) that contains duplicate entries based on only these columns [ArticleCode, StoreCode].

Currently I can filter duplicate rows using Aggregate transformation, but the problem is in the output rows I have only two columns [Article, StoreCode] and I need the other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just in the OLEDB Source component use SQL Command as  Source instead of Table name and write the following command (as a source):

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[ArticleCode]
  ,[StoreCode]
  ,[Address]
  ,[Number] FROM (

SELECT [ID]
  ,[ArticleCode]
  ,[StoreCode]
  ,[Address]
  ,[Number]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ArticleCode]
  ,[StoreCode] ORDER BY [ArticleCode]
  ,[StoreCode]) AS ROWNUM
 FROM [dbo].[Table_1]) AS T1

WHERE T1.ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of duplicates and select unique records by [ArticleCode, StoreCode]:

```
select top 1 with ties
    Id          , 
    ArticleCode , 
    StoreCode   , 
    Adress      , 
    Number
from
    YourTable
order by
    row_number() over(partition by ArticleCode, StoreCode order by Id)
```

But which of two records have to be selected when [ArticleCode, StoreCode] are equal and [Adress, Number] differ?

If Id is auto-increment then `order by Id` gets the first entered record, `order by Id desc` - the last.

You have somehow to define which [Adress, Number] pair among the duplicates is correct to be selected.